# How do I restrict the rights to the created PDA?

Tags: anchor, pda, authority

I want anyone to be able to create a PDA, but only I can edit it. I was able to do this with "constraint", but when I send the transaction I also need to send signers. Is it ok? Or it can be done differently

anchor-lang = "0.24.1"

Comment: Can you send some example code of what you've done so far? If I were implementing what you're describing, I'd have two instructions: InitializePda and EditPda.  The initialize would allow anyone to create the PDA, while edit would check that the signer is you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**example usage (anchor)**

```
pub struct ChangeUsername<'info> {
    #[account(mut,seeds=[payer.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub user: Account<'info, User>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
}
```

I have a struct that contains a `username`, and I want each user to be able to change **only** their `username`.

We can have the desired effect by creating a PDA (data account in this case) for each `user` with their `public key` as seeds. Let's call this `User` PDA

When a user wants to change their `username`. We check if the passed PDA is valid (matches a PDA generated using the `signer` publickey as seeds).

This means if a `user2` passes `user1` User PDA wishing to change their `username`. the transaction will fail since the PDA passed doesn't match the PDA generated inside the program using the `user2` (signer) public key as `seeds`

This constraint is checked implicitly in anchor here:

```
#[account(mut,seeds=[payer.key().as_ref()], bump)]
```

If the PDA is valid, the transaction goes through and the program will modify the `username`.